# The ICON_IMAGE feature is not supported on the current platform

Tags: java, desktop, platform

I have a problem with assigning an icon to an application on the taskbar. The code works fine when I run it on my mac device, but when I run it on my windows desktop an error is thrown saying that the current platform does not support the Taskbar.Feature.ICON_IMAGE feature.

How do I fix this? I can give system details and paste code if needed.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:compiler-errors]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Taskbar.setIconImage(Image)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html#setIconImage(java.awt.Image)):

> Throws:
>
> …
> `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the current platform does not support the `Taskbar.Feature.ICON_IMAGE` feature

The possibility that the feature is not supported under a particular platform, is clearly documented and needs your application to account for. You can test the availability with `isSupported​(Taskbar.Feature.ICON_IMAGE)`.

Keep in mind that unlike MacOS, Windows does not support the application state of having no windows open but being accessible from the task bar. Therefore, [associating an icon with every window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImage(java.awt.Image)) is already sufficient to control the application’s representation. AFAIK, augmenting the window’s icon with additional information via `setWindowIconBadge​` and `setWindowProgressValue​` etc works.